# Force refresh rate

Tags: nvidia, resolution

I want to make my monitor work at 59hz in 1920x1080 resolution because it flickers a bit at 60hz. Granted it is not in default options, so I need to forced it somehow. It was easy to do in windows, but in ubuntu I just can't do it, any option I try, like xrandr, just bounces of, because 1920x1080@59 is not supported by default. Is their some way to make it happen? My card is nvidia 9600gt with 310.32 drivers.

Using xrandr is give me this output:

> Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)   Minor opcode of failed
>   request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)   Serial number of failed request:  31 
>   Current serial number in output stream:  32

Using xrandr -r 59 gives:

> Rate 59.0 Hz not available for this size

I manage to change it to 1920x1080@59, but monitor rejected timing, so no luck for me. I wonder why it lets to work windows at 59hz?

If someone else will find this topic, I changed refresh rate by adding

> Option "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "TRUE"

Before modeline command, so it looks like this:

> Section "Monitor"
>       Identifier     "Monitor0"
>       VendorName     "Unknown"
>       ModelName      "Unknown"
>       HorizSync       30.0 - 81.0
>       VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
>       Option         "DPMS"
>       Option "ExactModeTimingsDVI" "TRUE"
>       Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync EndSection

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Calculate the needed modelines for your resolution

  ```
  cvt 1920 1080 59
  ```
- Add this new mode for the monitor with `xrandr`

  ```
  xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_59.00"  {add what you got from cvt} -hsync +vsync
  ```
- Add this new mode to the devices

  ```
  xrandr --verbose --addmode VGA-0  "1920x1080_59.00"
  ```
- Activate the new mode

  ```
  xrandr --output VGA-0 --mode "1920x1080_59.00"
  ```

---

By the way ...

```
xrandr -r 59
```

might work but this might depend on the card and/pr xrandr version.

---

Also do not forget to check your monitor: some displays allow you to set the refresh rate with the buttons on the monitor.

---

> Major opcode of failed request

The issue may be caused by the fact that the video card cannot read the EDID information from the monitor. In the device section of the xorg.conf, you can force the system not to use the edid information.

```
Section "Device"
<..>    
 Option         "UseEDID"   "FALSE"
EndSection
```

Another reason for the opcode error can be that the video driver does not allow non-edid modes (this is actually the default for current NVidia drivers). You might disable EDID as per above and that would work, but that is not optimal if your EDID information is actually correct, since you will lose things like monitor size information (expect wrong font sizes) and the default EDID modes reported by your monitor. Instead, use the following:

```
 Option         "ModeValidation"   "AllowNonEdidModes"
```

Another benefit with ModeValidation is that it allows more fine grained control (per output in case of multi-monitor setups); look in the NVidia driver readme for more information.

---

You can then add the modeline to `Section "Monitor"`

```
Section "Monitor"
Identifier     "Monitor0"
VendorName     "Unknown"
ModelName      "CRT-0"
HorizSync       28.0 - 55.0
VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
Option         "DPMS"
Modeline    "1920x1080_59.00"  {bunch of numbers from cvt} -hsync +vsync
EndSection
```

and the mode to `Section "Screen"`.

```
SubSection     "Display"
    Depth       24
    Modes      "1920x1080_59"
EndSubSection
```

Comment: As I said with xrandr I just get: (Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  153 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  31
  Current serial number in output stream:  32)
And I guess the line invalind parameter attributes is the key. Yeah, and as for xrand -r 59, Rate 59.0 Hz not available for this size

Comment: @user88114 you need to put that in the question ;)

Comment: Yay, now I'm stuck in 800x600 resolution, but at least flickering stoped :)

Comment: @user88114 lol :D what ARE you doing? :-X

Comment: Added what you said: this is my xorg: 
`Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 9600 GT"
    Option         "UseEDID"   "FALSE"
EndSection

    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
        Modes     "1920x1080_59.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection`

Comment: Did you not add in the `monitor` section?

Comment: yes, i did: `Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "DELL U2312HM"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
    ModeLine       "1920x1080_59.00" 169.00 1920 2040 2240 2560 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
EndSection`

Comment: I manage to change it to 1920x1080@59, but monitor rejected timing, so no luck for me. I wonder why it lets to work windows at 59hz?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else finding this in Google years later like myself, adding the following lines to your xorg.conf will disable all of the necessary checks to allow you to set any unsupported resolution on newer NVIDIA graphics cards (useful for virtual displays).
Under Section "Screen":

```
Option         "UseEDIDFreqs" "False"
Option         "ModeValidation" "NoDFPNativeResolutionCheck,NoVirtualSizeCheck,NoMaxPClkCheck,NoHorizSyncCheck,NoVertRefreshCheck,NoWidthAlignmentCheck AllowNonEdidModes"
```

then add the mode using the results from cvt and you're good to go!  If you'd like to attach a virtual display, just use

```
Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "HDMI-0"
```

replacing HDMI-0 with whatever display port you'd like your graphics card to use for the virtual display.