# Debugging Graphic errors

Tags: unity, intel-graphics

I  have got a graphic problem, but I don't have a clue how to find the source of it.

It seems like some parts of the display won't refresh when I am moving a window.
It also has to be some software error, as it is shown on the screen shot below.

Screen shot of the error.

[image]

The Computer is a modified version of the Dell Vostro 3450. It uses the Intel HD Graphics of the built-in Intel I5. (Some more information: 16 GB Ram, 500 GB HDD and 128 GB SSD.)

I'm running the 12.04 LTS.

Here the output of the requested command:

```
lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
```

--

It also seems to be a unity problem. I switched to Gnome classic and it runs fine. Also this problem occured just two days ago.I didn't use the Laptop for about a week, started it 2 days ago(usually its always in standby-mode, but it may have run out of power) and then recognized the error. After that i installed all updates, but the error is still there.

--

Okay, its gone. 
I ran Ubuntu-Tweek's janitor, which basically clears/removes the apt-cache, old kernels, package configuration and unneeded packages. Then i restarted unity and it looks all good.

Comment: Welcome to Asku Ubuntu! Can you post the output of lspci | grep VGA in your description? Also can you tell which version of Ubuntu you are using? It will be great if you can also provide more information about your hardware.

Comment: You must try installing the driver for your graphic card.

Comment: How do i do that? I tried the "additional Driver"-Option in the Systemsettings, but its not finding any driver. Also i'm running this System for about a year without that error and just 2 days ago it suddenly occors.

Comment: Strange..what did you do 2 days ago? did you do some update?

Comment: I did nothing. I didn't used the Laptop for about 1 week, started it  (usually its always in standby-mode, but it may have run out of power) and then recognized the error. After that i installed all updates, but the error is still there.

Comment: Try following these instruction : http://askubuntu.com/questions/166224/how-do-i-install-the-intel-graphics-driver-in-my-system

Comment: And since you are talking about "refreshing" here you may try changing your refresh rate . See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/257728/force-refresh-rate

Comment: You can also try instlling graphic drivers from here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/ . But it seems ubuntu comes with support for intel graphics ..

Comment: Please post the solution that solved your problem as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Ah thank you, i was just looking for a way to mark the question as solved :)

Comment: Due to my low reputation I'm not able to answer my own question within the first 8 hours. I'll do so as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

This glitch is due to system cache accumulation. Therefore one can solve it by clearing cache. To do this one may use Ubuntu Tweak's 'Janitor' feature. For installing Ubuntu tweak use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

Then open it from the dash. One can also open it from the terminal with the command:

```
ubuntu-tweak
```

Then one should select `Start Janitor`. Then select the cache one desires to clear from the subsequent window and then press `Clean` to remove cache. This should remove all unnecessary cache and solve the graphical glitch too.

If this doesn't work one may try making edits in CompizConfig settings manager which can be installed from here:

[image: Install via the software center]